# How to make a contract for a heterogeneous list with arbitrary number of values?

Tags: racket, contract

I am trying to make a contract for data that looks like this:

```lisp
'(a (b c) (d e) ...) ; a, b, c, d, e are all symbols
```

which is basically a list consisting of a symbol followed by an arbitrary number of lists of two symbols.

There is `list/c` but that only lets me make it with a fixed number of elements.
There is also `*list/c` which takes arbitrary initial values, followed by final fixed values, which is kind of the opposite of what I need.

How do I make a correct contract for my data structure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `cons/c` to apply one contract to the head of the list and another to the tail. What you want to express is that the head is a symbol and the tail is a list of pairs of symbols, so that'd be:

```
(cons/c symbol? (listof (list/c symbol? symbol?)))
```

Comment: `list-of` should be `listof`

Comment: @stchang Yes, it should. Thanks.